# How can some terminal programs ignore redirections and pipes?

Tags: linux, terminal, redirection

I've been fiddling with my network card tonight, when I noticed something when I run `ip link help`. Here are two cases when I noticed something different:

```
ip link help | grep set
```

and

```
ip link help > ip_link_help.txt
```

The first command has no effect, i.e. instead of redirecting the output of `ip link help` from the `stdout` to `grep`, the pipe is simply ignored and the output of `ip link help` is sent to the `stdout`.

The second case is a bit different. Though `ip link help` ignores the redirection symbol `>` and just prints to the `stdout`, file `file.txt` gets created anyway (but it's empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip link help` prints to standard error (stderr, file descriptor `2`); its standard output (stdout, file descriptor `1`) gets no data. Normally the two streams go to the terminal, so you cannot really tell them apart at first glance. `|` or `>` affects standard output. After you use it you know any data that gets redirected must have been destined to stdout; everything else – to elsewhere: usually to stderr, although some programs print some data directly to the terminal (`ip` is not one of them).

In your first case you can redirect stderr to the file descriptor of stdout, then build a pipe:

```
ip link help 2>&1 | grep set
```

where `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect the file descriptor `2` to whatever the file descriptor `1` points to. With this syntax, if the command printed something to stdout *and* stderr, everything would get to `grep`.

In the second case the shell creates (if needed) and truncates the file before `ip` is run. You can see this by invoking

```
a_command_that_doesnt_even_exist > foo.txt
```

`foo.txt` will be created despite the obvious error. This is because it's created first, before the shell even tries to run the command.

To capture stderr to the file use `2>` which redirects stderr only:

```
ip link help 2> ip_link_help.txt
```

Similarly `1>` redirects stdout only. Short `>` you used is strictly equivalent to `1>`.

---

An artificial example of a command that prints to the terminal in three different ways is

```
echo "standard output"; echo "standard error" >&2; echo "terminal" >/dev/tty
```

The output is:

```
standard output
standard error
terminal
```

You can easily redirect the first two lines. Try this:

```
(echo "standard output"; echo "standard error" >&2; echo "terminal" >/dev/tty) >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

This will still print the last line though.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not going to start an edit war but I deliberately chose to distinguish code (actual code that's *meant* to be run) from random output that *isn't* code (it's not meant to be run; yet it benefits from being formatted like code).

Comment: And it is commonly accepted here that terminal output can be displayed as ‘code’ as well. Adding quotes to code like that is really not something done on any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @JakeGould There's always room for improvement. :)